# How to fix Bootstrap dropdown: it stops working after I follow a link to another page (Turbolinks?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, turbolinks

I am trying to use a bootstrap navbar across several shopify landing pages. The problem I have is that when I click through a link in the navbar, then on the second page, the navbar will no longer dropdown. The other links still work, but the dropdowns will not.

I spent several hours trying to research this problem.
It seems like this is because of something called Turbolinks that pulls in the next page without fully reloading the navbar. I researched how to disable turbolinks or force a reload every time I click through, but I didn't understand the solutions that I found. They all talked about editing files, but the thing is that I am using bootstrap's online hosted script, so I can't edit the script files.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do while still using bootstrap's online script link?

This is my first time posting a question on StackOverflow, so bear with me and please let me know if there is a better way I could show my problem.

Here is the navbar code I am using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-Prison">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://emmausinternational.com/"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0386/2413/files/EmmausInternational_LogoHorizontalWhite_410x.png?v=1544739646" width="110" height="30" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active" width="100">
        <a class="nav-link" id="PrisonHome" href="https://emmausinternational.com/pages/prison">Prison Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown bg-Prison">
        <a class="nav-link bg-Prison dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Buy Courses
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">All Courses</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Prison Courses</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Most Popular Courses</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://emmausinternational.com/pages/emmaus-road2">Emmaus Road Curriculum</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown bg-Prison">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Connect
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">I Am A Prison Chaplain</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">I Represent A Church</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">I Want To Find A Prison Coordinator</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
      <div class="">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-0 mr-sm-2">
          <li class="nav-item active" width="100">
            <a class="nav-link" id="PrisonLogin" href="https://emmausinternational.com/account/login">LOGIN <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect that I can click through a link in my navbar dropdown and when I come to the resulting page, I can immediately open the dropdown again and navigate to another page. However, the dropdown will not open again until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is it losing JQuery somehow? Check the console for errors after you link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the following errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at L (instantclick.min.js?5325:1)
    at B (instantclick.min.js?5325:1)
    at N (instantclick.min.js?5325:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.J (instantclick.min.js?5325:1)

And that error is repeated three times. What does it mean?

Those errors also go away when I refresh, and then the dropdown works, so I definitely think it has to do with the problem.